# How do I tell to Agent Ransack to ignore files without any type/extension

Tags: agent-ransack

How can I do that kind of filtering ? 
I know `NOT:*.ext` but it is only to skip specific extensions what if I want Agent Ransack to skip files without type/extension

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to answer my own question :

```
NOT:*.
```